# Supernoob trying to learn

Tags: penetration-test, kali-linux

I'm very new to this. I have recently been using kali linux via rasberry pi and virtualbox. But I do not know what I'm doing. I have searched the web for good tutorials and have even paid for some via Udemy, but I have not learned anything. Is there anyone out there that might be able to help me from scratch to learn? I'm very eager to learn pentesting and pursuing it as a career. I've read that Kali Linux is a start but I have no clue what I am doing here. Any help would be great! thanks

Comment: Would give you an upvote for being straightforward, but I don't have enough privileges. To start, on the right hand side of the screen, look under "Related" and read through some of them to see what you're up against.

Comment: This isn't something you can learn from a few tutorials on the internet. It'll take years to get a good foundation. I suggest you start by learning how to program (which will take some time, too - don't expect to be able to master it in just a few months), which will give you an understanding of how software and computers work, and then reading as much as you can to broaden your understanding. Just running Kali linux doesn't help you understand any of the basics.

Comment: there are a lot of places to start. Kali linux is just one of them. if you want a job, just get a certification. but if you want to master it, then you should learn a lot from different areas like the network stack, Operating systems, Web Servers, programming and on and on. I agree with @Pascal that it will take years and that's why we are here to help each other out.

Comment: before use tools of kali linux to do an attack, you need to know the theory behind that attack

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/wiki/start

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest by starting in the right place, this is a Q&A site for Information Security, not a forum so I'm pretty sure this question will be closed soon. Answers cannot be opinion based, but I suggest you [Hak5](https://www.youtube.com/user/Hak5Darren) on Youtube, [SecurityTube](http://www.securitytube.net), Pluralsight.com have the [CompTIA Security+](https://app.pluralsight.com/paths/certificate/comptia-security-plus) and [CEH path here](https://app.pluralsight.com/paths/certificate/ethical-hacking) and [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/learning-path-ethical-hacking), and get a bachelor on any computer science area to begin with.

And about the forum and Q&A site, if you want to have a discussion about what's better and what's not, and opinions try the [Kali Linux Forums](https://forums.kali.org/).